# How can I define a generic method for Map<String, List<Object>> and MultivaluedMap<String, Object>?

Tags: java, generics, collections

I'm writing a http client library work for various platforms.(Java SE, Java EE)

With my Java SE implementation, I do

```
public void doSome(..., Map<String, List<Object>> params, ...);
```

With my Java EE implementation, I do

```
public void doSome(..., MultivaluedMap<String, Object> params, ...);
```

If I want to defined a generic abstract class for those methods, how can I define a method for both `Map<String, List<Object>>` and `MultivaluedMap<String, Object>`? Is there any elegant way to do this without a simple `T`?

Note that `Multivalued<K, V>` extends `Map<K, List<V>>`.

I, currently, am only capable of doing like this.

```
public abstract class AbstractClient {

    public void doSome(..., Map<String, List<Object>> params, ...);
}


public class JavaEEClient extends AbstractClient {

    static <K, V> MultivaluedMap<K, V> multivalued(Map<K, List<V>> map) {
        if (map == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (map instanceof MultivaluedMap) {
            return (MultivaluedMap<K, V>) map;
        }
        final MultivaluedMap<K, V> multi = new MultivaluedHashMap<>(map.size());
        multi.putAll(map);
        return multi;
    }

    public void doSome(..., MultivaluedMap<String, Object> params, ...) {
    }

    @Override
    public void doSome(..., Map<String, List<Object>> params, ...) {
        doSome(..., multivalued(params), ...);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I really have to admit that I'm miss-led myself. I actually started with JAX-RS only methods and started adding methods for Java SE with `URLConnection`.

It was O.K. with direct `MultivaluedMap` because `WebTarget`s and `Invocation`s accepts `MultivaluedMap`.

When I started adding classes and methods for `URLConnection`s, the problem arose.

I think I have to stick to `Map<String, List<Object>>` and use my `mutivalued` utility method.

Comment: But why you want this? Using just map is enough, one can pass anything that extends it, why do you want to have another method that accepts MultivaluedMap?

Comment: Java 8? Or previous?

Comment: If you have a MultivaluedMap, will you be using specific methods from this class?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Yes Java SE 8 or higher.

Comment: Why not just use `Function<String, List<Object>` then? Pass in `Map::get` or `MultivaluedMap::get` as needed. Or something completely different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you say that `MultivaluedMap<K, V>` extends `Map<K, List<V>>` then you can just do:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {

    public void doSome(..., Map<String, List<Object>> params, ...)
    ...
}
```

It will accept both MultivaluedMap and Map.

Comment: I know it does. But I want to know how to override(implement) it. See my edit.

Comment: Hmmm.. this is actually what I missed...I think... I really don't need defined an additional methods.

Comment: Yes, you don't need to. Unless you want to use some specific methods from `MultivaluedMap`.